# What does "side of things" mean?

Tags: idioms

Does it make sense to say something like this:

> Can you contact the tech support as you are more aware of the technical **side of things**?

I'm trying to ask someone to contact the tech support as they are more familiar of the technical aspects of something...

Is it **side of things** or **side of thing**?

Comment: It's definitely "side of things".  Also, you should either say, "contact tech support" (without **the**) or "contact the tech support department."

Comment: @CanadianYankee is there some reason you didn't just make that an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer extends on @Canadian Yankee's comment.

### Short answer

The correct answer is "**side of things**", as @Canadian Yankee pointed out.

### A note on "things"

"Things" can be used to describe general matters or topics as a "catch-all" phrase:

- How are things?
- Are things going smoothly?

When used in this type of context, "things" is always plural and never singular.

### On the plurality of the object of prepositions

A singular countable common noun does not come directly after "of" or any other preposition, so that should help in remembering the expression "side of things". Examples: 'in front of the table' (not 'in front of table'), 'next to a chair' (not 'next to chair')

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing wrong with **side of things**.

The implication behind the expression—in this case—is that there are two types of problems: those that are technical and those that aren't. People who address a problem can be thought of as being in one of two groups, and on "separate sides" of any given situation.

In the example sentence, the person being asked to contact technical support has more technical knowledge and will be better able to understand a technical conversation. They know more about the technical nature of the problem than does the speaker. (An unstated part of the sentence is a final "than I do.")

This particular expression takes the plural **things** because there are many components of the issue, some technical and others non-technical. (And, grammatically, if it *were* singular, it would be *side of* ***the*** *thing*.)